# Specifying pyODBC options (fast_executemany = True in particular) using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I would like to switch on the fast_executemany option for the pyODBC driver while using SQLAlchemy to insert rows to a table. By default it is of and the code runs really slow... Could anyone suggest how to do this?

Edits:

I am using pyODBC 4.0.21 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.13 and a simplified sample of the code I am using are presented below.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

def InsertIntoDB(self, tablename, colnames, data, create = False):
    """
    Inserts data into given db table
    Args:
    tablename - name of db table with dbname
    colnames - column names to insert to
    data - a list of tuples, a tuple per row
    """

    # reflect table into a sqlalchemy object
    meta = sa.MetaData(bind=self.engine)
    reflected_table = sa.Table(tablename, meta, autoload=True)

    # prepare an input object for sa.connection.execute
    execute_inp = []
    for i in data:
        execute_inp.append(dict(zip(colnames, i)))

    # Insert values
    self.connection.execute(reflected_table.insert(),execute_inp)
```

Comment: which version of pyodbc you are using?

Comment: pyODBC - 4.0.21; SQLAlchemy - 1.1.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for pyodbc

```
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.fast_executemany = True
```

Comment: Should I then use `crsr.executemany()` to execute my statements?

Comment: Thanks, it worked

!It's a bit bittersweet though. In principle, there is not need for SQLAlchemy then... :)

Comment: Yes true. Its for pyofbc not for sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 1.3, SQLAlchemy has directly supported [fast_executemany](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#fast-executemany-mode), e.g.,

```
engine = create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)
```